# Is there a word or phrase for describing 'the nth X-day of a month'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

As an example, Thanksgiving (US) is celebrated on the 4th Thursday of November. I'm looking for a way to describe that situation in a general sense. As in "Thanksgiving is a holiday that occurs __" or "Thanksgiving is a __" holiday. Monthly is close in a sense, although it doesn't quite capture the relative placement of the event. I'm also wondering what other words are associated with the concept. If there isn't a way of describing it well, I'd also be interested to hear ideas for coining a word for this.

For the curious, the context that this question arose from was in describing the manner in which one can schedule events. The title says "Monthly (Day-Relative)" with the subtitle "Choose the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th or 5th day of week or last day of month the event should occur". Day-relative seems to be an OK candidate, although it doesn't feel like it describes the situation completely.

Comment: "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" is unfortunately [out of scope](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: While the original context was from programming, I am not actually trying to name something. It was simply the context that brought to mind the fact that I have no way to express the concept concisely in English. I apologize for the confusion, as I see now that the second paragraph could be interpreted as being more than unnecessary information.

Comment: ... yearly holiday that occurs on ***designated Thursdays***  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Monday_Holiday_Act

Comment: Always good to clarify. Note that I didn't down vote/flag your question; I just wanted to give you a heads up on the rule. I am not sure why that prohibition is in the rules. It may be that Stackoverflow is simply a better venue for programming specific naming questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many years ago, I developed a program to maintain a listing of events and generate an e-mail detailing the events coming up in the next week.  I was rather proud of the repetition logic I had included and, when Google's calendar first came out, my options for repeating events were more robust and flexible than Google's.

In any case, the term I used for such events was ***day-of-month***.  This differed from *date-of-month* in that it was based on a specific day (e.g., 1st Monday, 2nd Friday, etc.) rather than a date within the month (e.g., the 15th of the month).

So my suggestion would be that: **day-of-month**

Comment: And thank you for the chance to remember that time in my life.